# Node.js and Websocket with wildcard in url path

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

is there a websocket framework for node.js where I can specifiy a wildcard in the websockets server path?

I want to use a path like so

/some/:id

In this case one should be able to connect to the urls that match the above string. The server has access to the id and can serve different channels.

For example: When using the module 'ws' one can setup a websocket server for one specific path on a http server:

```
new WebSocket.Server({server: someHttpServer, path:'/some/path'})
```

From here on you can connect to your websocket server from the browser with a WebSocket Object:

```
let client = new WebSocket('ws://.../some/path')
```

What I am looking for is something like this

```
new WebSocket.Server({server: someHttpServer, path:'/some/:id'})
```

so that I can connect to the websocket an deliver a predefined id

```
let clientA = new WebSocket('ws://.../some/idA')
let clientB = new WebSocket('ws://.../some/idB')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but express allows you to serve different 'routes' using a wildcard with almost identical syntax to what you suggest

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are no answers I assume there actually is none.

I found out the the shouldHandle method in the Websocket.Server class is repsonsible for deciding about the requested websocket path. This can easily be overwritten like so:

```
WebSocket.Server.prototype.shouldHandle = function shouldHandle(req) {
// Add your own logic and return `true` or `false` accordingly.
};
```

In order to do what I wanted to do you can just implement the following (not optimized for preformance)

```
  ...
  let customShouldHandle (req) {
    const pattern = new require('url-patter')('/some/:key/path')
    const url = require('url').parse(req.url).pathname
    const match = pattern.match(url)
    
    if (!match) {
      return false
    }
    
    if (!req.params) {
      req.params = {}
    }
    req.params.key = match.key
    return true
  }
    
  ...
  let server = new WebSocket.Server({ 
    server: httpServer, 
    path: this.customShouldHandle 
  })
  ...
```

Comment: Extremely useful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Following the original tutorial for `ws` package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws - it is possible to share HTTP(S) server between multiple sockets.

Routing can be handled in an `upgrade` callback.

Example:

```
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { parse } from 'url';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const server = createServer();
const wss1 = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true });
const wss2 = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true });

wss1.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  // ...
});

wss2.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  // ...
});

server.on('upgrade', function upgrade(request, socket, head) {
  const { pathname } = parse(request.url);

  if (pathname === '/foo') {
    wss1.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
      wss1.emit('connection', ws, request);
    });
  } else if (pathname === '/bar') {
    wss2.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
      wss2.emit('connection', ws, request);
    });
  } else {
    socket.destroy();
  }
});

server.listen(8080);
```